# I want to know the difference if the value in an object in JavaScript is undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

The variable 'bar' are all undefined. But is there any difference between `obj.bar` and `obj2.bar`?

```js
const obj = { foo: "foo" };
console.log(obj); // { foo: 'foo' }
console.log(obj.bar); // undefined 

const obj2 = { foo: "foo", bar: undefined };
console.log(obj2); // { foo: 'foo', bar: undefined }
console.log(obj2.bar); // undefined
```

Comment: A non-existing property returns the value `undefined`. The value `undefined` is the value `undefined`. There's no difference in the value `undefined`. However, there *is* a difference in that one object does not have a property `bar` and the other does.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: undefined is undefined. Both are same.

Comment: It seems the question you wanted to ask is not the difference between `obj.bar` and `obj2.bar`, but `obj` and `obj2`. I shouldn't get downvoted for answering your exact question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the `bar` is not declared. But in the second case, the `bar` is declared and defined to `undefined`.

Pretty tricky, the way to find it is, if you use `Object.keys(obj)`, you can't find `bar`.

Also, using `obj.hasOwnProperty('bar')` will give you false. Thanks to [deceze**♦**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) for [pointing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280035/i-want-to-know-the-difference-if-the-value-in-an-object-in-javascript-is-undefin/63280092#comment111898160_63280092) out.

```js
const obj = { foo: "foo" };
// console.log(obj); // { foo: 'foo' }
// console.log(obj.bar); // undefined 

const obj2 = { foo: "foo", bar: undefined };
// console.log(obj2); // { foo: 'foo', bar: undefined }
// console.log(obj2.bar); // undefined

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.keys(obj2));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('bar'));
console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('bar'));
```

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty('bar')`…

Comment: @deceze Yea, that's a good idea. Let me include and also give a credit to you.